# Eclipse Java - Jaxb2 plugin and WSDL

Tags: java, maven, jaxb

Hi I have to generate a WSDL. I have this xsd schema

```html
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://www.ima.eu/xml/cattolica"
           targetNamespace="http://www.ima.eu/xml/cattolica" elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <xs:element name="CreateRequestInput">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="customer" type="xs:string"  minOccurs="1"/>
                <xs:element name="user" type="xs:string"  minOccurs="1"/>
                <xs:element name="company" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1"/>
                <xs:element name="insuranceNumber" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="number" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="creationDate" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1"/>
                <xs:element name="answer" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="answerType" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="description" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1"/>
                <xs:element name="idquintuple" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1"/>
                <xs:element name="status" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="priority" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="idOTRS" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1"/> 
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:element name="CreateRequestOutput">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="CreateRequest" type="tns:CreateRequest"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:complexType name="CreateRequest">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="idCRM" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="status" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

Maven plugin Jaxb2 generate java objects correctly.
I did also soap config java file.

but the wsdl generated doesn't have xs:message part so with for example soap ui i cannot make request:

Why method CreateRequest is not generated in wsdl....
Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe there is a standard for naming the Responses and Requests?